# Why is my function looping python

Tags: python, loops

Weird issue I know that a function is being called twice some how but I dont know where or why its happening.

Heres my code:

```
  8 def getAccessSecretName():
  9         access_key = raw_input("Enter Access Key: ")
 10         secret_key = raw_input("Enter Secret Key: ")
 11         yourName = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
 12         print "Access Key: %s" % access_key
 13         print "Secret Key: %s" % secret_key
 14         print "Your full name is: %s" % yourName
 15         with open (tfVariables,"w") as text_file:
 16                 text_file.writelines(['access_key = \"'+ access_key +'\"\nsecret_key = \"'+ secre    t_key +'\"\n\n\n',
 17                                 'amis = {\n',
 18                                 '   ',
 19                                 'us-west-1 = '+ usWest1ami +'\n',
 20                                 '   ',
 21                                 'us-west-1 = '+ usWest2ami +'\n',
 22                                 '   ',
 23                                 '}'])
 24         return access_key, secret_key, yourName

 69 def makeMainTF():
 70         NameTag,mcGroupTag,mcIPTag = makeNameMCTag()
 71         access_key, secret_key, yourName = getAccessSecretName()
 72         with open (tfFileName,"w") as text_file:
 73                 text_file.writelines(['provider \"aws\" {\n',
 74                                       '  ',
 75                                         'access_key = \"${var.access_key}\"\n    ',
 76                                       '  ',
 77                                         'secret_key = \"${var.secret_key}\"\n    ',
 78                                       '  ',
 79                                         'region     = \"${var.access_key}\"\n    ',
 80                                       '}\n\n\n',
 81                                       'resource \"aws_instance\" \"example\"     {\n',
 82                                         '  ',
 83                                       'ami = \"${lookup(var.amis, var.region)    }\"\n',
 84                                         '  ',
 85                                         'instance_type = \"%s\" \n}' % instan    ceType,
 86                                         '\n\n\n\n',
 87                                         'tags {\n',
 88                                         '   ',
 89                                         'Name = \"%s\"\n' % NameTag,
 90                                         '   ',
 91                                         'Multicast = \"%s,%s\"\n' % (mcGroupT    ag,mcIPTag),
 92                                         '   ',
 93                                         #'Owner = \"%s\"' % " " % yourName,
 94                                         'Owner = \"%s\"' % yourName,
 95                                         '\n}\n\n\n'])
```

So here is what I expect to happen. When I run the code it will prompt the user for its access key, secret key and name. Then repeat it to the user once and write the information to a file. What happens when I call on both functions is this:

```
Enter Access Key: key1
Enter Secret Key: secret1
Enter your name: chowpay
Access Key: key1
Secret Key: secret1
Your full name is: chowpay
newnumber = 68
Name Tag: vlslabs67
Multicast Tag: vlslabmc, 172.16.0.67
Enter Access Key: key2
Enter Secret Key: secret2
Enter your name: chowpay2
Access Key: key2
Secret Key: secret2
Your full name is: chowpay2
```

Note that it's prompting the user to enter The keys and their name twice. Which doesnt make sense as this is all I have used to call the function:

```
getAccessSecretName()
makeMainTF()
```

Thanks!

---

I've corrected the code above with the correct function in line 53, it is getAccessSecret**Name**() , not getAccessSecret()

Correction again for adding the wrong function makeTfVars was posted in the question but makeMainTF() was , what was suppose to be in the question.

Comment: You are calling `getAccessSecretName()` from your calling code and again from `makeTfvars()`, but you don't show where that is called from.

Comment: who is `getAccessSecret()` ?

Comment: Also don't copy line numbers please.

Comment: Does `getAccessSecret()` call `getAccessSecretName()`? It would help if your code was a [mcve].

Comment: @wasp that was a mistake it should be getAccessSecretName() ive corrected that in an edit

Comment: @JulienBernu Sorry I thought that made it easier for people to call out "in line 53 you did such and such". Is it better educate to keep the line numbers out?

Comment: @cdarke perhaps i'm doing it incorrectly. the idea behind `53         access_key, secret_key = getAccessSecretName()` Is to get the 2 variables from the getAccessSecretName function so I can use them in the function of maketfvars(). new to python is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @PM2Ring , I took out functions that have no problem. But what I have above is exactly what I have running, there is nothing additional but the 2 functions and the 2 calls for those functions in the text. Did I miss something? Thanks

Comment: @chowpay - that is fine, but we don't see where `makeTfvars()` is being called, and you don't show the code for `makeMainTF()`.

Comment: @cdarke i'm doof. I made the correction, `makeTfvars()` was not suppose to be pasted in there. I was suppose to paste in `makeMainTF()` which I have now. .. I THINK I know the issue here, in line 71, `71         access_key, secret_key, yourName = getAccessSecretName()` the purpose of this was to make sure I can use those 3 variables in the function of `makeMainTF()`. But I've been told that what im actually doing is telling the function to run `getAccessSecretName()` again.  In which case maybe my question should be how do I return multiple variables so they can be used in other functions?

Comment: Seems to me, all you need do is to remove your bare call to `getAccessSecretName()` and just call `makeMainTF()`.  The values will then be set when you call `getAccessSecretName()` in  `makeMainTF()`.

Comment: Looks like this works:

Comment: @chowpay Yes: with line numbers it makes it harder for people to copy and paste your code in their editor.

Answer (score 0):

What I thought was a problem in the loop was a issue with how I thought variables in python get passed to other functions.

looks like doing this

```
71: access_key, secret_key, yourName = getAccessSecretName()
```

Doesnt mean make ^ variable values available from the function of getAccessSecretName(). Dumb mistake by me. Instead it means re-run the function to get the values which caused the user to be asked questions again.

The "fix" is adding

```
 10 def getAccessSecretName():
 **11         global access_key, secret_key, yourName**
```

and removing

```
  71: access_key, secret_key, yourName = getAccessSecretName()
```

This let me use my variables in other functions. Not sure if this is the right way to do it but it worked for me. Welcome to hear what a better way would be.

Thanks again